# Setting the SVG basic shape on a node-by-node basis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

(D3 beginner here)

I have the following snippet:

```
// myShape (node) group
// NB: the function arg is crucial here! nodes are known by id, not by index!
myShape = myShape.data(nodes, function(d) { return d.nodeId; });

// update existing nodes (reflexive & selected visual states)
myShape.selectAll('circle')
    .style('fill', function(d) { return (d === selected_node) ? d3.rgb(colors(d.nodeType)).brighter().toString() : colors(d.nodeType); })
    .classed('reflexive', function(d) { return d.reflexive; });

// add new nodes
var g = myShape.enter().append('svg:g');

g.append('svg:circle')
    .attr('r', 12)
```

But I would like to make this more flexible: instead of using only circles, I would like to use circles *and* polygons. This will be selected in a property in d:

```
var d = [
    { nodeId: 1, nodeType : 'type1' , shape: 'circle' },
    { nodeId: 2, nodeType : 'type2' , shape: 'triangle' },
];
```

Which means that, depending on d.shape. I must set 'svg:circle' or 'svg:polygon', and then set the radius (for the circle) or the points (for the polygons). I have tried to set the svg shape like this:

```
g.append(function (d) { 
    if (d.shape === 'circle' ) { return 'svg:circle'; } 
    else { return 'svg:polygon'; } } )
```

But this is not working: I am getting a:

```
Uncaught Error: NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8
```

It seems `append` does not accept a function? How can I set the svg shape on a node-by-node basis?

### EDIT

I have prepared this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/Icen/1) to show what I want to do.

Comment: Have you tried with the latest version? This should be supported, see [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/pull/1354).

Comment: Thanks, this looks to be what I need, but I am unable to put it to use. Do you have a little example?

Comment: It should work in exactly the way that you're using it. Do you have the complete code somewhere?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: Added a jsbin to que question

Comment: Ok, you actually have to create the element yourself and return it, not just the name. Modified jsbin [here](http://jsbin.com/eFAZABe/1). Works apart from the fact that there is no `polygon` element.

Comment: Thanks, that works. If you want to put it as an answer, I accept it. - you can also upvote the question :) The polygon is a valid svg shape (https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes) but it is not working because I am not setting the points, I think. I am setting the radius (r) for all types, which does not make sense. I have to set 'r' for circle, and 'points' for polygon, but I do not know how to add a variable attribute name

Comment: I'll add it as an answer. It might be easiest for you to just always add paths and vary the line generator.

Comment: Not clear what you mean. Maybe you can put that into the answer too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In recent versions of D3, you can `append` elements that are the results of function calls. That is, instead of passing a static name, you can pass a function that evaluates to the element to add.

It doesn't quite work the way you're using it -- it's not enough to return the name of the element from the function. Instead of

```
g.append(function (d) { return svgShape(d); })
```

where `svgShape` returns a string, you need to do something like

```
g.append(function(d) {
  return document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", svgShape(d));
})
```

and the corresponding shape will be created. I've updated your jsbin [here](http://jsbin.com/eFAZABe/1) to demonstrate.

In your case, it might be easier to always append a `path` and vary the line generator, i.e. the `d` attribute value. That is, for a circle you would pass in a function that returns a circular path, for a polygon a function that returns the particular polygon path etc.

Comment: Thanks. Still not clear how to add a dynamic attribute name. I'll ask that in another question.