# D3 force-directed graph: update node position

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, force-layout

I have just started with the [d3 library](https://github.com/mbostock/d3). I've taken a couple of days exploring the api and reviewing the examples and have started a project of my own based on the [force-directed graph](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045) example.

How can I update the position of node(s) after `tick` in case when instead of using simple shapes (`square`, `circle` ...) you are drawing nodes using paths?

I have provided an example that can be viewed here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EvZbx/4/)

```
var svg = d3.select('#view').attr({width: 300, height: 300});

var data = {
    "nodes": [
        {
           "id": "node_0",
           "name": "Node 0",
           "color": "blue",
           "h": 10,
           "w": 20,
           "t": "triangle"
        },....

    ],

    "links": [
        {
            "source": 0,
            "target": 1
        },...

    ]
};

var force = d3.layout.force().size([300, 300])
.linkDistance(50)
.nodes(data.nodes)
.links(data.links).start()

var link = svg.selectAll('.link').data(data.links).enter()
.append('line')
.attr('class', 'link')
.attr({"stroke": "#ccc", "stroke-width": 1.5});

var wrapper = svg.selectAll('.node').data(data.nodes).enter()
.append('g')
.attr('class', 'node')
.attr('x', function(d){return d.x})
.attr('y', function(d){return d.y});

var getShape = function(t, x, y, w, h){
    var points = (t == 'triangle') ? 
        [ [x + w/2, y], [x + w/2 , y], [x + w, y + h], [x, y + h]]
        : 
        [ [x, y], [x + w, y], [x + w, y + h], [x, y + h]];

    return d3.svg.line()(points)
}

var node = wrapper.append('path')
.attr('d', function(d){return getShape(d.t, d.x , d.y, d.h, d.w) })
.attr('x', function(d){return d.x})
.attr('y', function(d){return d.y})
.attr('fill', function(d){return d.color})
.call(force.drag);

force.on('tick', function(){
     link
     .attr('x1', function(d){return d.source.x})
     .attr('y1', function(d){return d.source.y})
     .attr('x2', function(d){return d.target.x})
     .attr('y2', function(d){return d.target.y})

     node
     .attr('cx', function(d){return d.x})
     .attr('cy', function(d){return d.y});
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For general shapes, you can simply use the `transform` attribute to move the nodes accordingly, see e.g. [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1062383).

Comment: Hi Lars thank you for answer.
I tried also with transform attribute but nodes are not any more connected with links.

Exemple -> [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TYPjD/1/)

Comment: You were applying the transformation twice, once to the wrapper and once to the actual element. You only need to have it once -- http://jsfiddle.net/TYPjD/2/

Comment: Thank you... I spent more then 3h solving this problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You're drawing your path elements with absolute positions using uppercase letters. Instead, try declaring the paths using relative coordinates by using lowercase letters. This will allow you to much more easily move the nodes around based on the force simulator using the svg `transform` property.

Regarding drawing paths with abolute and relative points:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d