# How do i add two different shapes to D3 forced directed graph based on shape field value?

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I am newbie to D3. I am using force directed graph. I want to add two different type of shapes at node's places.

My json is following:

```
{
  "nodes":[
    {"name":"00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01","group":0,"shape":1},
    {"name":"00:00:00:00:00:00:00:02","group":1,"shape":1},
    {"name":"00:00:00:00:00:00:00:03","group":2,"shape":1},
    {"name":"00:00:00:00:00:00:00:11","group":0,"shape":0},
    {"name":"00:00:00:00:00:00:00:21","group":1,"shape":0},
    {"name":"00:00:00:00:00:00:00:31","group":2,"shape":0},
    {"name":"00:00:00:00:00:00:00:32","group":2,"shape":0},
    {"name":"00:00:00:00:00:00:00:12","group":0,"shape":0},
    {"name":"00:00:00:00:00:00:00:22","group":1,"shape":0}
  ],
  "links":[
    { "source":  0,  "target":  0,  "value":  5 },
    { "source":  1,  "target":  1,  "value":  5 },
    { "source":  2,  "target":  2,  "value":  5 },
    { "source":  3,  "target":  0,  "value":  5 },
    { "source":  4,  "target":  1,  "value":  5 },
    { "source":  5,  "target":  2,  "value":  5 },
    { "source":  6,  "target":  2,  "value":  5 },
    { "source":  7,  "target":  0,  "value":  5 },
    { "source":  8,  "target":  1,  "value":  5 }
  ]
}
```

If shape value is 1, then draw circle, and if shape value is 0, then draw rectangle.
Force directed graph example link is: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045

I have tried example link JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mayurchavda87/Sc2xC/3/

Comment: [This thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/4EJDu1xOh8Y) discusses what you're looking for. There's also [this demo](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1062383).

Comment: Hi lars... I tried to do but i don't know how to pass parameters for circle instead of triangle and those symbol are not adjacent to edge.  Pls try to help me to draw circle. My JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/mayurchavda87/xr7x2/

Comment: The answer here applies to your question too:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/24792680/1070205

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this, as shown in e.g. [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1062383), by using a [symbol generator](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#wiki-symbol) and `path` elements instead of SVG elements for specific shapes. The code to add shapes becomes

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(data.nodes)
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol()
    .type(function(d) { return d3.svg.symbolTypes[d.s]; }))
  .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
  .call(force.drag);
```

Then you also need to change your `tick` handler to change the `transform` attribute of the `path` elements:

```
node.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
});
```

Complete jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Sc2xC/4/).

Comment: Can I do something like .enter().append(function(d) { add span or div or whatever depending on data; })? I get NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element is null when I try to return an element created using jQuery

Comment: It may be better to ask a separate question about this where you can provide more detail.

Comment: correction for d3.v4 uses `d3.symbol().size(...).type(...)`