# How to give different Shape or image icon for different nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to give different shape or image icons for different nodes.
Like, for Target node i.e dark blue you can see in the js fiddle I want to give as a rectangle to an image icon and for a lighter circle with different shape or image icon.I have followed this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18509792/d3-force-directed-graph-different-shape-according-to-data-and-value-given) also but cant able to make it work.
Here is the js fiddle like:
https://jsfiddle.net/AmitSah/bp6p3p92/

```
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
    radius = 10;

/*svg.call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
   svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
}));*/
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.node_id; }).strength(1) )
    //.force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(radius + 1).iterations(4))
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));


// projection definition
var projection = d3.geoAlbers()
    .scale(1280)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

// path generator definition for major cities, including point radius
var path = d3.geoPath()
    .projection(projection)
    .pointRadius(2);

// draws the states
d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LogicalInsightscg/Web-Mobile-Dashboard/master/us_new.json", function(error, us_new) {
  if (error) return console.error(error);
svg.selectAll(".states")
    .data(topojson.feature(us_new, us_new.objects.states).features)
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "states " + d.id; })
    .attr("d", path);

// adding state boundaries
    svg.append("path")
    .datum(topojson.mesh(us_new, us_new.objects.states))
    .attr("d", path)
    .attr("class", "state-boundary");


d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LogicalInsightscg/Web-Mobile-Dashboard/master/nodesandlinks.json", function(error, graph) {
  if (error) throw error;


// build the arrow.
svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
    .data(["end"])      // Different link/path types can be defined here
  .enter().append("svg:marker")    // This section adds in the arrows
    .attr("id", String)
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", 15)
    .attr("refY", -1.5)
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
  .append("svg:line")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

   var link = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.referrals); })
       .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)");




  var node = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
      //.attr("fixed", true)
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
                   return projection([d.longitude, d.latitude])[0];
           })
           .attr("cy", function(d) {
                   return projection([d.longitude, d.latitude])[1];
           })
/*       .call(d3.drag()
          .on("end", dragended)); */
       .call(d3.drag()
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended)); 



   simulation
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .on("tick", ticked);  

   simulation.force("link")
      .links(graph.links);



     node.attr('fx', function(d) { return projection([d.longitude, d.latitude])[0]; })
        .attr('fy', function(d) { return projection([d.longitude, d.latitude])[1]; });

     link.attr('x1', function(d) { return projection([d.source.longitude, d.source.latitude])[0]; })
        .attr('y1', function(d) { return projection([d.source.longitude, d.source.latitude])[1]; })
        .attr('x2', function(d) { return projection([d.target.longitude, d.target.latitude])[0]; })
        .attr('y2', function(d) { return projection([d.target.longitude, d.target.latitude])[1]; });

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.node_name; });

   function ticked() {
    link
        .attr("distance", 10)
//        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
//        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr('x1', function(d) { return projection([d.source.longitude, d.source.latitude])[0]; })
        .attr('y1', function(d) { return projection([d.source.longitude, d.source.latitude])[1]; })
        .attr('x2', function(d) { return projection([d.target.longitude, d.target.latitude])[0]; })
        .attr('y2', function(d) { return projection([d.target.longitude, d.target.latitude])[1]; });

    node.attr('cx', function(d) {if (d.group > 0) { return projection([d.longitude, d.latitude])[0]; }
                                             else  { return d.x; }})
        .attr('cy', function(d) {if (d.group > 0) { return projection([d.longitude, d.latitude])[1]; }
                                             else  { return d.y; }});

  }


/*   function ticked() {
     link.attr('x1', function(d) { return projection([d.source.longitude, d.source.latitude])[0]; })
        .attr('y1', function(d) { return projection([d.source.longitude, d.source.latitude])[1]; })
        .attr('x2', function(d) { return projection([d.target.longitude, d.target.latitude])[0]; })
        .attr('y2', function(d) { return projection([d.target.longitude, d.target.latitude])[1]; });

     node.attr('r', width/100)
        .attr('cx', function(d) { return projection([d.longitude, d.latitude])[0]; })
        .attr('cy', function(d) { return projection([d.longitude, d.latitude])[1]; });

  } */
 });
});

function dragstarted(d) {
if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}
```

Can anyone help me to do this?

**EDITED:**
Kindly see this image:

[Network Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXAwA.png)

```
d3.selectAll(".company").append("rect")
    .attr("width", 20)
    .attr("height", 20)

.data(someData)
.attr("x", function(d) {
   if (d.cat == 2)
     {
                   return projection([d.longitude, d.latitude])[0];
     }      
     })
           .attr("y", function(d) {
  if (d.cat == 2)
     {
                   return projection([d.longitude, d.latitude])[1];
     }      
     });
```

Thanks,
Amit Sah

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to have something in the data that you can use to set the attributes, i.e.

```
.attr('stroke-color', function(){
if
```

`(d.dataAtt = someAttribute, return black)
else if
(d.dataAtt = otherAttribute, return white)`

Or if you want to set the target nodes to a different colour, you could use d3.select to select all the node id's in the target link array, then change the attributes of only those nodes. Setting the node id might help select the correct nodes (see the bottom line):

```
var node = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "nodes")
.selectAll("circle")
.data(graph.nodes)
.enter().append("circle")
  .attr("r", 5)
.attr("id", d.graph.nodes.id)//or something
```

Edit:

```
   var node = svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", function(){
    if
(d.dataAtt = someAttribute, return Aclass)
else if
(d.dataAtt = otherAttribute, return Bclass))//it would be easiest to separate the nodes by class
        .data(graph.nodes)
        .enter()
        .attr("id", d.graph.nodes.id)//or something

d3.selectAll(".Aclass")
    .append("rect")

d3.selectAll(".Bclass")
    .append("circle")
```

You could use the source/target array to select the nodes where there id is in one or the other, but without seeing your data, I don't know if that would be appropriate.

Comment: I don't want to set different color for different node.I want to give different shape like. Rectangle, Triangle OR I some images or icon for different nodes.Can u have any idea how to incorporate it in this visualization.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Bull/4btFx/1/ From the answer you linked above, you need to do something with the data to define which ones you want as circles/rect. Or a way to select them (you could post-modify them). If you're nodes are only ever source/target (not both a source and a target), you could use that to select them. I'll add an edit.

Comment: Thank you @Oliver Houstom I have tried the same and I am getting the rectangle but not at the correct longitude and latitude position.Kindly look at the code https://jsfiddle.net/AmitSah/2yogkpg4/ . It is not a working example to I am using the mentioned code in Js fiddle.

Comment: In the code d.cat==2 means it is indicating for target node. That I have saved in array data.

Comment: My Array is in this formate:
someData.push({
  longitude:  this.dataInterface.getRowHeaders(i).getHeader(0).getName(),
    latitude:  this.dataInterface.getRowHeaders(i).getHeader(1).getName(),
         value: this.dataInterface.getMetricValue(i,0).getValue(),
      tooltip:tooltip_value,
       sizevalue: source_size_by_value,      
      sizeby:sizeof,
      cat:1, // 2 for target node
      group: defaultsource
      
  });

Comment: you know "cx" and "cy" won't work for rectangles right? you need "x" and "y" to define the top left corner of the rectangle, then adjust the rectangle to centre it... i.e. add 10 to long and lat to put the centre of a 20*20 rectangle and the given coordinates.

Comment: Thank you @Oliver Houston. I am new in this d3 world. I was not knowing that for rectangle I have to use 'x' and 'y'.But when I am using 'x' And 'y' even though I am not getting the rectangle at proper locations.Can you please help me on this by updating the js fiddle which I have posted in my previous comment.I didn't understand what do u mean by " then adjust the rectangle to center it... i.e. add 10 to long and lat to put the center........"

Comment: And is it the same case if I will try to use some image instead of a rectangle.Because basically, I want to use an image at the end.

Comment: Kindly see my edited post.there I have attached an image which I am getting after applying the logic which you said.

Comment: No worries, I'm new to it as well, I've had a look at the data and it looks like you don't have any attributes to select the nodes by, i.e. css classes, d3.select(".company") is looking for anything with the class "company".

Comment: have a look at this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element and this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/rect to better understand svg elements. and console.log(node)/console.log(graph) will help you understand what's going on in your data.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Oliver Houston. I got my solution by removing the .data(someData) from rectangle creation part.